# Start a program with a path containing spaces given

Tags: c++

I have a string for a command, e.g.:
start `C:\Users\...\test application.exe`
with a path that has spaces.
Now I want to use the `system()` function to start it up:

```
system(command.c_str());
```

But the problem is, it doesnt start because the path contains a space.
What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Like all commands with spaces in windows you need to wrap it in `""`.

Comment: Quote the path. Remember to escape the quotes if you are setting it via a string literal.

Comment: If I comment this to: start "C:\Users...\test application.exe" it doesnt work either...I have no idea how this stuff works,:/

Comment: Did you escape the `\\`? I just use / instead of '\\` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do I have to do to fix this?

The first thing you need to know is that `system()` uses the shell to execute the command, and the shell wants you to enclose the program path with `""`, if the path contains a space.

Using the current C++ standard, the easiest way to fix is to use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
std::string command = R"("C:\Users\test application.exe")";
system(command.c_str());
```

Otherwise (and for older C++ standards), you need to escape **all** of the special characters:

```
std::string command = "(\"C:\\Users\\test application.exe\")";
                     // ^   ^      ^                     ^
```

Comment: @Cody I think this formulation is better.

Comment: @Cody Hmm, that's a hard nut to crack. I can't see any use case ITM where I _wouldn't_ in this situation.

Comment: Note that on windows you need to be extra careful when [quoting arguments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/). (I know this doesn't apply to the OP - yet, at least)

Comment: @user786653 Yeah, that's a good point. But I at least tested if the escaping works correctly on a normal windows command shell.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I wasn't criticizing your answer, just pointing out to the OP (and future visitors) another potential pitfall related to quoting on windows aside from the program filename.

Comment: @user786653 Neither I was criticizing your comment, just the opposite.

Comment: Yeah, you mentioned that in your re-edit of my edit. Which I said was fine. Sorry for the confusion. I was just trying to explain why I made the edit I did in the first place, not point out a flaw with the answer *currently*.